# XML to CSV with nested and repeatable nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am working with Dublin Core encoded metadata files that I would like to convert to CSV. I am trying to arrive at the output below

`identifier1|||identifier2|||identifier3|||identifier4,datestamp1|||datestamp2|||2010-04-27T01:10:31Z,setspec1,title1|||title2,subject1|||subject2,baseURL|||xxxxx|||xxxxx`

Note that repeatable elements are seperated by three pipe symbols (|||), while elements are seperated by commas (,).

I've managed to arrive the the stylesheet below, however, I am struggling with the following

(1) How do I go about defining a generic template to enable me delimit nodes with commas?

```
<xsl:template match="GENERIC MATCH">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="current()" />
  <xsl:if test="position() = last()">,</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Using `Input File` below as example, I basically want GENERIC MATCH to enable me dynamically process `level 2` nodes (header, metadata and about) and delimit results with commas.

(2) How do I determine if element is the last child node so I can conditionally include a comma after?

```
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="record" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="record">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//metadata/oai_dc:dc/dc:title|//metadata/oai_dc:dc/dc:subject" />
  <xsl:if test="not(metadata/oai_dc:dc/node()/position()=last())">#####</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="dc:title">
  <xsl:value-of select="." />
  <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())">||</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="dc:subject">
  <xsl:value-of select="." />
  <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())">||</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Input File

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<record>
  <header>
    <identifier>identifier1</identifier>
    <datestamp>datastamp1</datestamp>
    <setSpec>setspec1</setSpec>
  </header>
  <metadata>
    <oai_dc:dc>
      <dc:title>title1</dc:title>
      <dc:title>title2</dc:title>
      <dc:creator>creator1</dc:creator>
      <dc:subject>subject1</dc:subject>
      <dc:subject>subject2</dc:subject>
    </oai_dc:dc>
  </metadata>
  <about>
    <provenance>
      <originDescription altered="false" harvestDate="2011-08-11T03:47:51Z">
        <baseURL>baseURL1</baseURL>
        <identifier>identifier3</identifier>
        <datestamp>datestamp2</datestamp>
        <metadataNamespace>xxxxx</metadataNamespace>
        <originDescription altered="false" harvestDate="2010-10-10T06:15:53Z">
          <baseURL>xxxxx</baseURL>
          <identifier>identifier4</identifier>
          <datestamp>2010-04-27T01:10:31Z</datestamp>
          <metadataNamespace>xxxxx</metadataNamespace>
        </originDescription>
      </originDescription>
    </provenance>
  </about>
</record>
```

I am working with `xslt 1.0` using `xsltproc`.

Comment: I'm having some trouble seeing a clear connection between your source data and your expected output.  What determines which kinds of fields should be in the output?  The source data has `baseURL`s  and `metadataNamespace`s intermingled with `identifiers` and `datestamp`s.  Should those be in the output?  What determines in which order they should be listed?

Comment: Yes, I need those in my output file as well. I just edited my original post. the order of the output is not important but in an ideal case, I'd want them to appear as they are in the source file.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Your sample input has a `creator` field that's not in the output, and the sample output has an "identifier2" field that's not in the input, but I can just disregard those discrepancies too, right?

Comment: right, missed those out as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <!-- A key on all leaf nodes -->
  <!-- *[not(*)] matches any element that is a leaf node
       i.e. it has no child elements. Here, the elements' names are being
       used as the key value. -->
  <xsl:key name="kNodeType" match="*[not(*)]" use="local-name()"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- Use Muenchian grouping to apply the "group" template to the first of
         each leaf node with a distinct name. -->
    <xsl:apply-templates
      select="//*[not(*)][generate-id() = 
                          generate-id(key('kNodeType', local-name())[1])]"
      mode="group" />
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- This template will be used to match only the first item in each group,
       due to the grouping expression used in the previous template. -->
  <xsl:template match="*" mode="group">
    <!-- Skip the comma for the first group, output it for all others -->
    <xsl:if test="position() > 1">,</xsl:if>
    <!-- Apply the "item" template to all items in the same group as this element
         (i.e. those with the same name) -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kNodeType', local-name())" mode="item" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="item">
    <!-- Skip the delimiter for the first item in each group;
         output it for all others -->
    <xsl:if test="position() > 1">|||</xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, this produces:

> > identifier1|||identifier3|||identifier4,datastamp1|||datestamp2|||2010-04-27T01:10:31Z,setspec1,title1|||title2,creator1,subject1|||subject2,baseURL1|||xxxxx,xxxxx|||xxxxx

Comment: perfect! exactly what I needed. Do you mind helping me understand what's going on here? I understand keys but some expressions, like `*[not(*)]` don't make sense to me.

Comment: Sure.  I've added comments above.  Please let me know if I can clarify anything further.